# Fastify Nestjs Cors bug

Tags: nestjs, fastify

I found below cors warning when use fastify nestjs server (@nestjs/platform-fastify of 8.4.5 version)

> [FST_MODULE_DEP_FASTIFY-CORS] FastifyWarning.fastify-cors: fastify-cors has been deprecated. Use @fastify/cors@7.0.0 instead.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

how to solve this?

Comment: I enable cors in fastify nestjs server

Answer (score 0):

It was addressed in this [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/9507) and I think it will be deployed in the upcoming version 9.0.0